# Is it considered harmful to commit readable CSS in addition to SCSS source?

Tags: css, git, sass

The project I work on uses SCSS, which is super. When pushing code to the repo, the rule is to avoid all compiled or generated code and only commit the original source.

I find it useful to track and diff the clean, readable, pre-minify CSS code. So I'd like to version the CSS too, not just the SCSS. However, my CTO opposes this "because it's not right and not useful". His point is valid in a perfect world, but in practice this actually hurts my workflow.

What do other front-end developers do? Is it considered harmful to commit readable CSS in addition to SCSS source? Should I suck it up and change my workflow because it's the right thing, even if I am pretty sure this is not as efficient?

Comment: Provided everything's going through the same compiler, there's _zero_ reason to need to diff on the compiled CSS too.  That's paranoid, bro.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know it's paranoid, but I'm like that and this would help me do may paranoid thing better.

Comment: Could you tell us what your workflow is so we might be able to help you get rid of that paranoia? ;)

Answer (score 7):

Is anyone else writing CSS straight without compiling?  Is there a non-zero chance that someone is committing CSS other than you?  If not, then you're opening Pandora's box by inviting CSS to be committed as you'll inevitably end up with an environment where someone makes a change to the output CSS without making the change in the SCSS.  Once that drift starts to happen, it can be a huge pain in the butt to solve.

I know, I've been there before with LESS.  Visual Studio automatically compiles a minified and non-minified CSS file from this.  Occasionally, the FE Devs I mentored would make a change in Web Inspector and then commit those changes as they solved the problem.

*HOWEVER*, once someone else pulled repo, compiled the project, and re-committed, those changes would be blown away due to the LESS not reflecting what was in the actual CSS at that point.

Don't invite drift into your project.  This is a basic DRY principle.  One source means only one point of failure and will save headaches for you, your managers and the QA organization at your company.

Comment: Completely agree. I'd like to add the conflicts this might generate as well. If every developer is not using the exact same library and version of SASS for the compilation, every single change is going to add a conflict on the compiled files or change every single compiled file because of some new rule on indentation or even a compilation timestamp. You don't want that.